# Inseparable terminal and running cost in optimal control problems?

Tags: optimal-control

I have the following version of time optimal control problem for a two dimensional system with terminal equality and state inequality constraint.
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{J}(u)= (T-\int_{0}^{t_f}\mathrm{d}t)^2,\;\;\;\;\; T = \text{given}\\
\text{s.t.}\:\; \dot{V}= AV+bu\\
v_1(t_f)= \bar{V}, v_2(t) \leq V_{g},\;\; \forall t\\
0<u(t)<\mathcal{U}\;\; \forall t, \;\;\; \mathcal{U}=\text{given} \\
v_1(0) = a,\;\; v_2(0) = b, \;\;\;\;\; a,b =\text{given} 
\end{align}
Now I know how to solve this problem when the cost is separable in terms of running and terminal cost. I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new variable $V_{N+1}$ s.t. $\dot V_{N+1} = 1 $. Now your functional reads
$$
J(u) = \big(T- V_{N+1}(t_f) \big)^2
$$
and you have a Mayer problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142675/increasing-convergence-rate-using-optimal-control-and-pontryagin-maximum-princip