# Increasing convergence rate using Optimal Control and Pontryagin Maximum Principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, optimal-control, dynamic-programming, nonlinear-dynamics

My question is in addition to [Tuning the optimal control synthesized according to the Pontryagin maximum/minimum principle and choosing the cost function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246166/tuning-the-optimal-control-synthesized-according-to-the-pontryagin-maximum-minim), but requires help from the mathematical side of view.

Given system of ODE:

$F=\begin{cases} \dot{x}=g \\ \dot{g}=-k_g \cdot g+k_g \cdot\frac{df}{dx}+u \\ \dot{h}=-k_h \cdot h+k_h \cdot\frac{d^2f}{d^2x} \end{cases}$

where:

$\boldsymbol{X}=(x,g,h)$ - vector of variables, which is moving towards some final state $\boldsymbol{X}_f$;

$f=e^{-(x-c)^2}$;

$c$ - unknown constant;

$k_g,k_h$ - parameters, can be selected from the range $3>k_g,k_h>1$;

$u$ - control input;

*Feature:* this system go to a state in which $g=0$ and $sign(h)=-1$.

**Algorithm:**

To ensure usual convergence, I chose the cost function in the form:
$J= \int_{0}^{\infty} (g+u^2) dt$

1. Hamiltonian:  $H=-(g+u^2)+\boldsymbol{\lambda} \cdot F$
   where $\boldsymbol{\lambda}=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)$
2. Co-state equation: $\dot{\lambda}=\frac{dH}{d\boldsymbol{X}}$
   where $\boldsymbol{X}=(x,g,h)$
3. Solve equation for control input $u$: $\frac{dH}{du}=0$

4.Write resulting system of equation:$\begin{cases} F=... \\ \dot{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}=... \end{cases}$

5. Solve numerically.

**Problem:** in what ways can the cost function be written to maximize convergence rate to the final state $\boldsymbol{X}_f$ for given parameters $k_g,k_h$.

$J= \int_{0}^{\infty} (???)dt$

I would be glad and grateful for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that you want $g$ to appear linearly inside the integral, since I think $g$ can be negative as well? And usually the convergence becomes faster when one penalizes the input less, so scale $u^2$ by some positive constant and let that constant closer and closer to zero.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen

Thanks for the answer. You have understood the task correctly. The physical meaning of what you proposed is quite clear. We reduce the requirements for the minimum energy consumption for movement. Are there any other ways?

Comment: $J= \int_{0}^{\infty} (g^2+u^2) dt$ as for the linearity of the variable $g$. Of course, the integrand can be corrected to the following.